# Passing String error

Tags: android, eclipse, string, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a string from an activity to another. I went through many of the questions refering to "Intents" and "Passing strings" but I keep getting the same error. Could someone point me out where I'm mistaken? Here's my code

First Activity

```
    package com.example.youtube;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Testing extends Activity {

    public static String IPAddress = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);


        //Alert Popup
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Step 1");
        alert.setMessage("Enter IP Address\n(i.e: 192.168.0.1)");       


        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          Editable value = input.getText();
          // Do something with value!
          IPAddress = value.toString();

            //Fire that second activity
            Intent intent = new Intent( getBaseContext(),LoginIn.class);
            intent.putExtra("keyword1",IPAddress);  
            startActivity( intent);

            if (IPAddress != ""){

                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.youtube.LoginIn"));
            }
          }
        });



        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
          }
        });

        alert.show();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

Second Activity

```
    package com.example.youtube;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class LoginIn extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        Button bverify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify1);
        final TextView testview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String value1=extras.getString("keyword1");

        bverify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.youtube.domotique"));
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.youtube"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Testing"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".LoginIn"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.youtube.LoginIn" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".domotique"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.youtube.domotique" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.youtube/com.example.youtube.LoginIn}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.youtube.LoginIn.onCreate(LoginIn.java:23)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

I tried many form of Intent, and at different location in my code but my App keeps crashing when pressing "Ok", when my Second activity is launched.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: please post the logcat of your error

Comment: Give please stack trace.

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Typically there is no need to call `System.exit(0);` in Android apps, `finish()` will close the current activity for you and you call close everything with the appropriate Intent flags.

Comment: How should I post Logcat? I tried with "Code" but it makes a longe list that is unreadable. Thanks, I will replace the "==". And for the System.exit(0), I put those because my app wouldnt close everytime I'd pause it, so I found my way to force it, temporaly.

Comment: Is my Intent structure correct? Am I putting it at the right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment this section in your first activity and execute the code, if you got the same error then you might not be registered "com.example.youtube.domotique" and "com.example.youtube.LoginIn" in your manifest

```
if (IPAddress != ""){

                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.youtube.LoginIn"));
                }
```

Comment: My app works well whenever I don't use the Intent part, but since I added those lines, it crashes when opening the second activity.

Comment: you have to register those intents in your manifest file. Can you put your logcat error??

Comment: How am I suppose to register my intents in my manifest? I didn't do this part, I didn't see this part anywhere in the tutorial. And could you please tell me how to post a logcat? I tried, but it's really messy so i took it off :S

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer works, but why is this part crashing my app? How does my app launch my second page when my the activity that starts it is commented?